# C++ char[] - как вывести из предложения все слова, содержащие в себе подстроку

Tags: c++, строки, char

Мне нужно вывести все слова, содержащие три символа **"при"**, которые мы нашли из последнего слова. Результатом вывода должно быть **"привет"** и **"приехал"**. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать, и желательно при помощи простых функций.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    char str[] = "привет, как дела? Ты приехал?";
    char three_letters[4];

    int indeks = -1;

    for (int i = strlen(str); i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ')
            indeks = i;
        else
            break;
    }

    cout << indeks << endl;

    strncpy_s(three_letters, str + indeks, 3);

    cout << three_letters << endl;
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если слова должны начинаться с "при" — смотрите в сторону `strncmp`, если просто содержать — `strstr`, для разбиения строки на слова — `strstr`. И еще — `for (int i = strlen(str); i > 0; i--)` — так вы начинаете с завершающего нулевого символа и заканчиваете вторым от начала. Индексы в любом массиве начинаются с нуля!

Comment: Для разбиения строки на слова - `strtok`.